# Whats the first step in creating a blockchain based certification system?

Tags: blockchain, amazon-managed-blockchain

I have an understanding of how blockchain dAPPS are built, but I do not know which network I should use or which language to write the script in. Right now I am thinking about using AWS, but I am open to other suggestions.